# Grouping Records by header SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query;

```
SELECT      STOCK_CODE,
            dbo.manu_STOCK.DESCRIPTION, 
            QTY_IN_STOCK, 
            Quantity, 
            ForecastDate
FROM        [FS25-w2k8\SQLEXPRESS].sagel50_46772.dbo.SalesForecastLines AS SalesForecastLines1 
INNER JOIN  dbo.manu_STOCK 
    ON      SalesForecastLines1.ProductCode = dbo.manu_STOCK.STOCK_CODE
```

This brings up the following information;

```
STOCK_CODE        DESCRIPTION         QTY_INSTOCK            Quantity      ForecastDate
  523                 gel                  12                   10           01/08/2014
  523                 gel                  12                   10           08/08/2014
```

I want to be able to modify the query so that it displays the following formation

```
Stock Code Description  WK1  WK2

523           gel        22   22
```

So it will sum qty in stock and quantity on the first date and the column will be called wk1, second week - wk2 etc.

Can you advise on this please?

Comment: How is that output a pivot of the query?

Comment: This is just a select statement?

Comment: Could you advise me on how to put together the Select statement?

Comment: would this get arbitrarily wide or is there a limit to how many weeks will pop up as in 52 weeks?

Comment: It will only go up until 52 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to pivot the results for 52 weeks, you can use the following query. This will pivot data for 52 weeks. This is just concept, I could not test this query.

```
SELECT  *  FROM
( SELECT
            dbo.manu_STOCK.STOCK_CODE AS [Stock Code],
            dbo.manu_STOCK.DESCRIPTION, 
            DATEPART(WEEK,[Date]) Wk,
            QTY_IN_STOCK + Quantity AS Stock

  FROM  [FS25-w2k8\SQLEXPRESS].sagel50_46772.dbo.SalesForecastLines AS SalesForecastLines1 
        INNER JOIN  dbo.manu_STOCK 
            ON SalesForecastLines1.ProductCode = dbo.manu_STOCK.STOCK_CODE
) AS Source
PIVOT
(
SUM(Stock) 
FOR WK IN
([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
,[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20]
,[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30]
,[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40]
,[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50]
,[51],[52])
) AS PVT ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Stock TABLE
(
    STOCK_CODE INT,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
    QTY_INSTOCK INT,
    QUANTITY INT,
    FORECASTDATE DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Stock
( STOCK_CODE, DESCRIPTION, QTY_INSTOCK, QUANTITY, FORECASTDATE )
VALUES
( 523, 'gel', 12, 10, '01/08/2014' ),
( 523, 'gel', 12, 10, '08/08/2014' )

SELECT 
    s.STOCK_CODE, 
    s.DESCRIPTION,
      s.STOCKYEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 1 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 2 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 3 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 4 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 5 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 6 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk6,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 7 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk7,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 8 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk8,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 9 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk9,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 10 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk10,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 11 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk11,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 12 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk12,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 13 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk13,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 14 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk14,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 15 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk15,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 16 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk16,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 17 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk17,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 18 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk18,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 19 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk19,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 20 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk20,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 21 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk21,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 22 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk22,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 23 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk23,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 24 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk24,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 25 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk25,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 26 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk26,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 27 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk27,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 28 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk28,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 29 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk29,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 30 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk30,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 31 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk31,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 32 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk32,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 33 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk33,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 34 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk34,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 35 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk35,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 36 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk36,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 37 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk37,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 38 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk38,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 39 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk39,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 40 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk40,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 41 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk41,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 42 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk42,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 43 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk43,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 44 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk44,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 45 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk45,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 46 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk46,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 47 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk47,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 48 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk48,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 49 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk49,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 50 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk50,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 51 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk51,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 52 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk52,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.STOCKWEEK = 53 THEN s.QTY_INSTOCK + s.QTY ELSE 0 END) Wk53
FROM
(
    SELECT s.STOCK_CODE, s.DESCRIPTION, DATEPART(YEAR, s.FORECASTDATE) STOCKYEAR, DATEPART(WEEK, s.FORECASTDATE) STOCKWEEK, SUM(s.QTY_INSTOCK) QTY_INSTOCK, SUM(s.QUANTITY) QTY
    FROM @Stock s
    GROUP BY s.STOCK_CODE, s.DESCRIPTION, DATEPART(YEAR, s.FORECASTDATE), DATEPART(WEEK, s.FORECASTDATE)
) s
GROUP BY s.STOCK_CODE, s.DESCRIPTION, s.STOCKYEAR
ORDER BY s.STOCK_CODE, s.DESCRIPTION, s.STOCKYEAR
```

Group by the code, desc, year and week and then sum by week for each week of the year (adding extra week depending on day beginning / end of the year falls.